# Iterating form controls that are created at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I create form dynamically on the client side.

I want to iterate it, but know how many fields were created only in client runtime.

based on

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspxIn ASP.net

I want to add some data to the model

`<% for (int i = 0; i < **3**; i++) { %>`

how can I make the loop run `someClientVar` times?

**Update:**

this is my scenario:

The client has an "expand" button.

It adds unknown number of fields to a form.

I wanted to submit them via a model (I created an object with many fields).

in addition there are some not shown to the UI kind of

'current context' data I want to send the server as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a disconnect of context here that seems to go misunderstood:

By the time your client script has had a chance to create the variable you wish to use, the server side code, by definition, has already executed. It would be *kind of* possible the other way around, but not this way.

If you could provide more information on your scenario, such as what data the form is constructed from, then a solution could possibly be provided. As it stands, one can't (short of using sheer guesswork).